# How to place the JSON data in a list in a Ktor server?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have been trying to get Json data from `dummyjson` and place them into an `Array` in the `ktor` server. But it just won't work.

`Application.kt`:

```
fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "0.0.0.0") {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            gson {
                setDateFormat(DateFormat.LONG)
                setPrettyPrinting()
            }
        }
        val client = HttpClient(CIO)
        val products: Array<Product> = client.get("https://dummyjson.com/products").body()
        configureRouting()
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

I could create the `client` but I am not allowed to use the `get` method because it says `Suspend function 'get' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`.

Then, in `configureRouting.kt` I defined the client and used the get method. It works and returns the String to the client.

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO)
    routing {
        get("/get-all-products"){
            val product: String = client.get("https://dummyjson.com/products").body()
            call.respond(product)
        }
}
```

However, what I want to achieve is without the client's request, the server can automatically load all the JSON file from `dummyjson`, and place it in a list. But it just keep giving me the same error if I place this get method outside the routing.

Comment: You can make the `main` function suspendable by adding the `suspend` keyword, instantiate a client and make a request there before the server initialization. Then you can pass products or the client to the `configureRouting` method as a parameter.